# unicodeエスケープすることなく、文字列をjsonオブジェクトに変換したい

Tags: python, python3, json, unicode

`json.loads(text)` メソッドを利用して、文字列をjsonオブジェクト(dict型)に変換したいのですが、全角スペースが'\u3000'と変換されてしまいます。
全角スペースのまま変換することは可能でしょうか？

◇試したコード

```
import json
from typing import Dict

text: str = '{"code":"123", "message":"テスト　メッセージ"}'
print(type(text), text)

json_map: Dict[str, str] = json.loads(text)
print(type(json_map), json_map)
```

◇実行結果

```
<class 'str'> {"code":"123", "message":"テスト　メッセージ"}
<class 'dict'> {'code': '123', 'message': 'テスト\u3000メッセージ'}
```

dict型に変換後も、
`{'code': '123', 'message': 'テスト　メッセージ'}`
と全角スペースのままにできないでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

それは全角スペースのままか'\u3000'とエスケープ表記されるかといったprintで表示している見た目上だけの違いです。
たとえばタブ文字がインデントして表示されるかエスケープ表記されるかといった違いと同じです。
文字自体はどちらも同じ全角スペースです。

```
s = 'テスト　メッセージ\tです'
print(s) # テスト　メッセージ      です

l = [s]
print(l) # ['テスト\u3000メッセージ\tです']
print(l[0]) # テスト　メッセージ      です

print(s == l[0]) # True
```

Comment: 見た目が違うだけなこと理解しました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

すでに解決済みのようで余計なレスかもしれませんが・・・

> 全角スペースが'\u3000'と変換されてしまいます。

それは Unicode Escape Sequence (以下 UES と書きます) という形にエスケープされた結果です。

UES というのは \uxxxx という形で表される Unicode 文字で、xxxx はその文字の Unicode コードになります。

ちなみに、ASP.NET Core MVC では非 ASCII 文字は全てデフォルトで UES になります。ASCII 文字でも HTML-sensitive characters はエスケープされます。例えば、< とか > はそれぞれ \u003C および \u003E になります。

Python でどこまでエスケープされるのかは分かりませんが、U+3000 については Space_Separator [Zs] category に属するということなのでエスケープされたのだと思います。

詳しくは以下の記事や、

ASP.NET Core MVC の Unicode Escape Sequence (UES)
http://surferonwww.info/BlogEngine/post/2020/03/11/aspnet-core-mvc-controller-json-method-replaces-non-ascii-characters-with-5cuxxxx.aspx

それからリンクが張ってある以下の記事の回答を見てください。

Can't serializ the '\u3000' when using with UnicodeRanges.All
https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/22147

Comment: ありがとうございます。